# How to parse google protobuf response received from kubernetes watch APIs (curl)?

Tags: kubernetes, curl, protocol-buffers

I am using curl to perform watch api requests - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes

When I get response in JSON it's easy to parse it and get complete event. But, I want that response in a protobuf format (application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf).

So, how to parse that response (complete response and not the partial response received in curl)?